# How to execute "group by" queries in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I need to be able to execute the following query or something similar:

```
SELECT count(1) AS userCount, f.gh
FROM f 
WHERE f.location.coordinates[1] < <MAX_LAT> 
AND f.location.coordinates[1] > <MIN_LAT>
AND f.location.coordinates[0] > <MIN_LNG> 
AND f.location.coordinates[0] < <MAX_LNG>
GROUP BY f.gh
```

I have a collection that stores user's coordinates on a map. When zoomed in, I want to display individual users locations, but when zoomed out, I want to display the amount of users in a location grouped by their 5-character geohash. This query is exactly what I want, however you cannot run group-by queries over rest api, as mentioned in the docs.

[Queries that cannot be served by gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/querying-cosmosdb-resources-using-the-rest-api#queries-that-cannot-be-served-by-gateway)

It doesn't offer any alternatives to this, and I'm still pretty new to Cosmos. How can I successfully run this query?

Comment: Can you use one of the 4 SDKs? .NET, Java, JS and Python. It's super difficult using the REST API directly. The SDK's hide a ton of complexity.

Comment: Nope, I'm using .NET core API and it throws the same error. DISTINCT is another very important operator I need to use for other parts of my database, and it seems impossible to use either of these operators besides in the query directly in the portal which is useless

Comment: If you're using .NET Core then please download and use the .NET SDK v3. Nuget package is here. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.cosmos/. Also, I don't know why you're writing a query like this. Seems like this would better be handled by using ST_WITHIN. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-geospatial-query

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that I was trying to call "group by" through azure function bindings, and not the actual .NET SDK Nuget package. Thanks for the help.